# SQLiteStudio tipos de dados

Tags: sqlite3, tipagem

Estou usando o SQLiteStudio para modelar uma base de dados. Na hora de criar os campos de uma tabela, reparei que ele dispõe de alguns tipos de dados que não aparecem na documentação do SQLite. Por exemplo, Na combobox onde escolhemos o tipo da coluna, ele tem: BOOLEAN, DOUBLE, procurei na documentação do SQLite e não encontrei esses tipos de dados.

Answer (score 3):

A própria [**documentação**](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) informa que não possui `boolean` e informa que valores booleanos são guardados como `int`, sendo `false = 0` e `true = 1`:

> **1.1 Boolean Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Daí, você trata na sua aplicação quando o valor deste campo for 0, é `false` e quando for 1, é `true`.

E quando ao `double`, você pode usar `real`, que é também a recomendação da documentação, conforme a tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referencias:**

[SQLite - Data Type](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm)

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Opa, Diego.
Isso eu ja tinha visto. Minha pergunta é por que o [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) permite criar colunas com esses tipos de dados se o SQLite não suporta.
[PRINTSCREEN](http://oi66.tinypic.com/2h68unr.jpg)

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva ele deve fazer as conversões conforme descrito na documentação, é interessante você verificar qual o tipo dos campos da tabela, provavelmente o que você selecionou boolean, ele criou como int, e o double deve estar como real.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva na verdade sua pergunta não é essa que você pôs no comment. Mas se a intenção é que seja, você pode [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar esse complemento.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Na imagem da resposta, coluna do "meio", mostra o tipo de "afinidade" (`Affinity`) da coluna e se você consultar o link `SQLite - DataType` da resposta, lá explica o porquê: "aumentar a compatibilidade do SQLite com outros databases". Não é o SQLiteStudio quem "cria" esses tipos

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Não dá para colocar um link direto, mas a frase está logo no início do item: `2.0 Type Affinity` :)