# Migrations HasMaxLength x HasColumnType

Tags: orm, migrations, entity-framework-core

Estou criando uma tabela simples de teste com `EF Core e SQlite`

Segue o primeiro teste no qual o `modelbuilder` cria uma `migration` (mostrado logo abaixo)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Curso>()
        .Property(c => c.Nome)
        .HasColumnType("varchar(51)");
}
```

> Trecho Migration criada pelo model builder acima

`Nome = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(51)", nullable: true),`

Segundo teste:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Curso>()
        .Property(c => c.Nome)
        .HasMaxLength(52);
}
```

> Trecho Migration criada pelo model builder acima

`Nome = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 52, nullable: true),`

O resultado dos dois testes são refletidos de forma diferente na criação do bando de dados, a primeira cria um campo corretamente `varchar(51)` já a segunda cria um campo padrão `Text`

Fiquei na dúvida.

Não era para os dois criarem o mesmo campo tipo `varchar`?

Exite alguma diferença entre essas duas propriedades (`HasMaxLength e HasColumnType`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Não era para os dois criarem o mesmo campo tipo `varchar`?

Não, é para ele criar o tipo definido como padrão pelo banco [`SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) que é [Text](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Quando a responsabilidade é transmitida para a geração do banco ele coloca o tipo padrão que podem ser, dependendo do tipo de dado da `classe`:

- **NULL.** *The value is a NULL value.*
- **INTEGER.** *The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.*
- **REAL.** *The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.*
- **TEXT.** *The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).*
- **BLOB.** *The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.*

Dentro do tipo `Text` existe variações ***`(cast)`*** que são considerado **`Text`**:

- **CHARACTER(20)**
- **VARCHAR(255)**
- **VARYING CHARACTER(255)**
- **NCHAR(55)**
- **NATIVE CHARACTER(70)**
- **NVARCHAR(100)**
- **TEXT**
- **CLOB**

***Referencia:*** [Affinity Name Examples](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples)

Por isso que quando configurou para `varchar(51)` o banco aceitou a configuração, porque, [é permitida](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples).

> Exite alguma diferença entre essas duas propriedades (`HasMaxLength` e `HasColumnType`)?

Sim, são métodos que definem ***configurações diferentes***:

- [`HasMaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionprimitivepropertyconfiguration.hasmaxlength(v=vs.113).aspx): define o tamanho máximo de caracteres de um campo.
- [`HasColumnType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringcolumnconfiguration.hascolumntype(v=vs.113).aspx): define o tipo de dado que será aceito ou armazenado em um determinado campo de sua tabela.

Essas duas configurações não são exatamente processados para `SQLite` em campos [Text (ou variações)](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples) que tem como [informação no site](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length): *The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to* **2** <sup>31</sup>**-1** *or 2147483647*. A validação deve ser feita com `ViewModel` decorando com [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj129537.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `[MaxLength(52)]`, resumindo, para `SQLite` as configurações de mapeamento não tem validade nenhuma no caso especifico citado, diferente para `SQLServer`, `MySQL` e `PostGreSQL` que serve como restrição e informação retornando **erros** do **banco** para **aplicação**.

> ***Conclusão***

Configure normalmente dessa forma:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
           .Property(c => c.Nome)
           .ForSqliteHasColumnName("nome")                                            
           .IsRequired();
```

sendo isso o padrão para campos texto em `SQLite` **(Text)** e se por ventura quiser ***restringir/validar*** crie `ViewModel` com [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj129537.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) para ter o controle necessário nos **models**

***Links:***

- [Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)
- [SQLiteStudio tipos de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112151/54880)
- [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, `HasColumnType` ficou claro pra mim a explicação, agora `HasMaxLength: define o tamanho máximo de caracteres de um campo` onde exatamente esta limitação (52 caracteres) é aplicada?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow deve ser aplicada somente na validação, porque, se você não especifica (**isso só acontece no SQLite**) o tipo ele coloca Text. Vamos fazer o seguinte vou testar a validação, e até amanhã coloco o teste... Tudo que está na resposta foi feito código e testando no Visual Studio. vlw.

Comment: Ok, com essa explicação a resposta fica completa. Eu também estou testando no Visual Studio.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow eu fiz teste, e o que mais me intrigou que as configurações de tamanho de comprimento de campo são ignoradas pelo banco `SQLite`, que na verdade aceita  `2147483647`  que é um comprimento grande então, talvez isso nunca chegue a acontecer. Diferente em outros bancos que se não estiver isso configurado, exemplo, SQLServer se você não coloca o tamanho ele cria um campo `varchar(255)`. Bom eu deixarei ela dessa forma até que encontre mais informação, mas, é assim que ele funciona.

Comment: Mas com relação ao `HasMaxLength` onde exatamente é aplicada a validação? Seria no `frontend`? Seria interessante um exemplo,mesmo simples, da utilização.

Comment: No caso de SQLite em nenhum lugar. @rubStackOverflow, tem que usar a tecnica de ViewModel

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer uns testes já que vou utilizar MVVM no teste que estou fazendo.

Comment: Qualquer duvida estamos ai e qualquer descoberta eu posto também @rubStackOverflow